# How to unset default notification manually Magento

Tags: magento-1.9

In magento 1.9, i want to unset notification manually. For example on adding product to cart we got message "xyz added to cart successfully". I want to unset that type of message/notification manually. 
Please anybody can suggest me, where may be file about it.

Comment: Hello Guys, anyone know about this ?

Comment: do you want to hide success and error messages from site ?

Answer (score 0):

Open file

> app/design/frontend/default/your_theme/template/checkout/cart.phtml

Or

> app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/cart.phtml

Go to line 47 and remove or comment this code:

```
echo $this->getMessagesBlock()->getGroupedHtml();
```